# Call popen() on a command with Chinese characters on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, encoding, popen, utf-16

I'm trying to execute a program on a file using the popen() command on a Mac. For this, I create a command of the form `<path-to_executable> <path-to-file>` and then call popen() on this command. Right now, both these two components are declared in a char*. I need to read the output of the command so I need the pipe given by popen().

Now it turns out that path-to-file can contain Chinese, Japanese, Russian and pretty much any other characters. For this, I can represent the path-to-file as wchar_t*. But this doesn't work with popen() because apparently Mac / Linux don't have a wide _wpopen() like Windows.

Is there any other way I can make this work? I'm getting the path-to-file from a data structure that can only give me wchar_t* so I have to take it from there and convert it appropriately, if needed.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Seems like one of those days when you just end up pulling your hair out.

So I tried using wcstombs, but the setlocale call failed for "C.UTF-8" and any of its permutations. Unsurprisingly, the wcstombs call failed returning -1 after that.

Then I tried to write my own iconv implementation based on some sample codes searched on Google. I came up with this, which stubbornly refuses to work:

```
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "WCHAR_T");
// error checking here

wchar_t* inbuf = ...; // get wchar_t* here
char outbuf[<size-of-inbuf>*4+1];

size_t inlen  = <size-of-inbuf>;
size_t outlen = <size-of-inbuf>*4+1;

char* c_inbuf  = (char*) inbuf;
char* c_outbuf = outbuf;

int ret = iconv(cd, &c_inbuf, &inlen, &c_outbuf, &outlen);
// more error checking here
```

iconv always returns -1 and the errno is set to EINVAL. I've verified that `<size-of-len>` is set correctly. I've got no clue why this code's failing now.

**Edit 2:**

iconv was failing because I was not setting the input buffer length right. Also, Mac doesn't seem to support the "WCHAR_T" encoding so I've changed it to UTF-16. Now I've corrected the length and changed the from encoding but iconv just returns without converting any character. It just returns 0.

To debug this issue, I even changed the input string to a temp string and set the input length appropriately. Even this iconv call just returns 0. My code now looks like:

```
iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16");
// error checking here

wchar_t* inbuf = ...; // get wchar_t* here - guaranteed to be UTF-16
char outbuf[<size-of-inbuf>*4+1];

size_t inlen  = <size-of-inbuf>;
size_t outlen = <size-of-inbuf>*4+1;

char* c_inbuf  = "abc"; // (char*) inbuf;
inlen = 4;
char* c_outbuf = outbuf;

int ret = iconv(cd, &c_inbuf, &inlen, &c_outbuf, &outlen);
// more error checking here
```

I've confirmed that the converter descriptor is being opened correctly. The from-encoding is correct. The input buffer contains a few simple characters. Everything is hardcoded and still, iconv doesn't convert any characters and just returns 0 and outbuf remains empty.

*Sanity loss alert!*

Comment: Mac OS file names are encoded in UTF-8, so that's what you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an UTF-8 string for `popen`. For this, you can use [`iconv`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/iconv.3.html) to convert between different encodings, including from the local `wchar_t` encoding to UTF-8. (Note that on my Mac OS install, `wchar_t` is actually 32 bits, and not 16.)

**EDIT** Here's an example that works on OS X Lion. I did not have problems using the `wchar_t` encoding (and it is documented in the `iconv` man page).

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

char* utf8path(const wchar_t* wchar, size_t utf32_bytes)
{
    char result_buffer[MAXPATHLEN];

    iconv_t converter = iconv_open("UTF-8", "wchar_t");

    char* result = result_buffer;
    char* input = (char*)wchar;
    size_t output_available_size = sizeof result_buffer;
    size_t input_available_size = utf32_bytes;
    size_t result_code = iconv(converter, &input, &input_available_size, &result, &output_available_size);
    if (result_code == -1)
    {
        perror("iconv");
        return NULL;
    }
    iconv_close(converter);

    return strdup(result_buffer);
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t hello_world[] = L"/éè/path/to/hello/world.txt";

    char* utf8 = utf8path(hello_world, sizeof hello_world);
    printf("%s\n", utf8);
    free(utf8);
    return 0;
}
```

The `utf8_hello_world` function accepts a `wchar_t` string with its **byte length** and returns the equivalent UTF-8 string. If you deal with pointers to `wchar_t` instead of an array of `wchar_t`, you'll want to use `(wcslen(ptr) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: I'd read about iconv's reputation to be nasty to implement. I know now it's well deserved.

Comment: @Sameer, nasty to implement or nasty to use? Looking around, it looks simple enough. I'll see if I can use it and post an example.

Comment: Thank you very much zneak for your effort. I really appreciate it.

I gave your code a try and here's the result. If I use wchar_t like you have, or even UTF-32, for the fromEncoding in iconv_open, iconv errors out with "Illegal byte sequence". If I use UTF-16, which is actually wrong, iconv runs successfully but convertes 0 bytes. I checked on my 10.6 Mac and wchar_t is 32 bits, just like you said.

I'll explore this and update when I find something. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sameer, there may be another problem in your conversion pipeline then. If your read routine is "guaranteed to be UTF-16" but returns/fills a `wchar_t` pointer, then it's almost certainly neither well-formed UTF-16 nor UTF-32.

Comment: It was as you had suspected. The wchar_t I got from the in the input buffer was indeed garbled. Once I fixed the read routine, both iconv and wcstombs started working as expected. The only catch was that I needed to set the locale for *both* the functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X uses UTF-8, so you need to convert the wide-character strings into UTF-8.  You can do this using [`wcstombs`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/wcstombs.3.html), provided you first switch into a UTF-8 locale.  For example:

```
// Do this once at program startup
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
...
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
wchar_t *wideFilename = ...;  // This comes from wherever
char filename[256];  // Make sure this buffer is big enough!
wcstombs(filename, wideFilename, sizeof(filename));
// Construct popen command using the UTF-8 filename
```

You can also use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to do the UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion for you if you don't want to change your program's locale setting; you could also roll your own implementation, as doing the conversion is not all that complicated.

Comment: Would (length of wideFilename) x 3 suffice for filename, since I'm guessing wcstombs would split multibyte chars into 2 or 3 bytes as required?

Comment: No, you'd need at least ((length of wideFilename)*4 + 1), since each wide character could potentially decode to up to 4 bytes in UTF-8, plus 1 for the NUL terminator.

Comment: Any idea why setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8") call would fail? It's causing the wcstombs call to fail as well.

Comment: I got the locale name wrong, try using `en_US.UTF-8` instead.  You can see the list of locales available on your system by running `locale -a` from the command line.